# iCell.Value takes too long

Tags: excel, vba

I have this simple code that loops through 400 rows.

It works but it takes 30 secs.

The problem comes from the   **iCell.Value = stringaDecriptata** line

Is there any way to speed up the code?

```
Sub Decr()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim counter As Integer
Dim stringaCriptata As String
Dim stringaDecriptata As String
Dim carattere_da_decriptare As String
Dim carattere_da_sostituire As String
Dim iCell As Range

For Each iCell In Range("A1:BK460")
    stringaDecriptata = ""
    lunghezza = Len(iCell.Value)
    indirizzo = iCell.Address
    
    For counter = 1 To lunghezza
        stringaCriptata = iCell.Value
        carattere_da_decriptare = Mid(iCell.Value, counter, 1)
        carattere_da_sostituire = Chr(Asc(carattere_da_decriptare) - 10)
        
        stringaDecriptata = stringaDecriptata & carattere_da_sostituire
    Next
    
    iCell.Value = stringaDecriptata
Next iCell

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code in new workbook with A1:BK460 filled with ten letters each. It ran in under 2 secs. I think you should try this yourself. If it's faster in a clean workbook, I think your problem is elsewhere in the original workbook.

Comment: There are 28980 cells in that range, which is almost 30.000. This means that 1000 cells are handled per second. Is that so bad?

Comment: `stringaCriptata = iCell.Value` Is this line needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. It places the range to be processed in an array and all process is done in memory. Only at the code end it drops the processed result, at once:

```
Sub Decr()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range, arr As Variant, counter As Integer
 Dim stringaCriptata As String, stringaDecriptata As String, carattere_da_decriptare As String
 Dim carattere_da_sostituire As String, lunghezza As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = sh.Range("A1:BK460")
 arr = rng.Value2  'place the range in an array for faster processing

 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)        'iterate between the array rows
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)  'iterate between the array columns
         stringaDecriptata = ""
         lunghezza = Len(arr(i, j))
         For counter = 1 To lunghezza
            stringaCriptata = arr(i, j)
            carattere_da_decriptare = Mid(arr(i, j), counter, 1)
            carattere_da_sostituire = Chr(Asc(carattere_da_decriptare) - 10)
            
            stringaDecriptata = stringaDecriptata & carattere_da_sostituire
        Next counter
        arr(i, j) = stringaDecriptata 'place the decrypted string back in the array element
    Next j
 Next i

 'drop the processed array result, at once:
 rng.Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Iterating between each range cell takes time, and even more time to place back the processed value, **one at a time**.

Then, it is good to make the habit to declare all involved variables. To let VBA helping you if forgot it, you should place  `Option Explicit` on top of the module...

I did not test the code, but I think it should work and be faster. I am just curious how much it takes to process your range...

Comment: It takes 1 msec!! Thanks!